# Test a property that's populated with the FromServicesAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, asp.net-core

## Question

We have a controller property that populates using the `FromServicesAttribute`.

```
[FromServices]
public IGenericRepository<TodoItem> TodoItemRepository { get; }
```

We want to test using this property. How do we mock it? For instance, if we were using constructor injection, we could pass the mock implementation to the constructor. How do we do this with a property this way?

## Our Current Approach

This is how we're currently doing it with `Moq`.

```
[Fact]
public void GetAll_GetsCollection()
{
    // setup mock repository
    var all = new List<TodoItem>()
    {
        new TodoItem(),
        new TodoItem(),
        new TodoItem()
    };            

    var mockRepo = new Mock<IGenericRepository<TodoItem>>();
    mockRepo.Setup(x => x.All()).Returns(all);

    // setup mock unit of work
    // including what the [FromService] property will return
    var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    mockUnitOfWork
        .Setup(x =>x.TodoItemRepository)
        .Returns(mockRepo.Object);

    // test controller
    TodoController controller = new TodoController(mockUnitOfWork.Object);
    var result = controller.GetAll();
    Assert.Equal(3, result.Count());
}
```

This does work and pass the tests. Maybe it's good enough. We're new to TDD.

Comment: Are you using `FromServices` instead of construction injection because this service is not used by all actions on the controller? if yes, I prefer using the repository as a parameter on the action with `FromServices` decorated on it...MVC handles `FromServices` decorated parameters specially...that is it has a model binder for it...having it as a parameter makes it very clear that an action depends on a service making it better for unit testing..

Answer (score 5):

Make the property settable (internal if needed) and use the `InternalsVisibleTo` to make the setter visible to the test assembly. Then, after you construct the object in the test code, set the property.

Or, if you use DI in your test code, create a fake `IGenericRepository<TodoItem>` and let the DI container inject it.

Comment: I'm really interested to learn how we could create a fake `IGenericRepository<TodoItem>` and then *let the DI container inject it.* How could we let the DI container inject it when we're running from our unit tests? Currently, we configure our DI container within the Startup.cs class in the project that we're testing. Do we just, for instance, use another Startup.cs that's in our test project, configuring the DI container there? In other words, setup a DI container in our unit test project?

Comment: `FromServices` decorated properties are assigned values at the ModelBinding stage which is prior to the action invocation. That is at the model binding stage MVC gets the service from DI and assigns value to the property(and as Victor mentioned, you need to have a setter for your property otherwise MVC would not be able to assign a value to the property). So for this scenario even if you setup DI container for unit testing, your property would not be populated as you are just unit testing controller and do not have a model binding stage. Continued...

Comment: Anyways an exmaple for the way you an assign a DI container for unit testing is here: https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/test/MusicStore.Test/StoreControllerTest.cs#L20-L26